# Allow scheduling of pods on Kubernetes master?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I set up Kubernetes on CoreOS on bare metal using the [generic install scripts](https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-generic-platforms.html). It's running the current stable release, 1298.6.0, with Kubernetes version 1.5.4.

We'd like to have a highly available master setup, but we don't have enough hardware at this time to dedicate three servers to serving only as Kubernetes masters, so I would like to be able to allow user pods to be scheduled on the Kubernetes master. I set --register-schedulable=true in /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service but it still showed up as SchedulingDisabled.

I tried to add settings for including the node as a worker, including adding worker TLS certs to /etc/kubernetes/ssl, adding those settings to kubelet.service, adding an /etc/kubernetes/worker-kubeconfig.yaml that pointed to those certs, and added that information to the /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-proxy.yaml. I used my existing nodes as a template for what to add. This registered another node under the master's hostname and then both it and the original master node showed up as NotReady,SchedulingDisabled.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873164/are-there-issues-with-running-user-pods-on-a-kubernetes-master-node) indicates that scheduling pods on the master node should be possible, but there is barely anything else that I can find on the subject.

Answer (score 59):

If you are using Kubernetes 1.7 and above:

```
kubectl taint node mymasternode node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Comment: I believe this command should be with a minus at the end to actually remove this taint from the master. Right?

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. @VictorG - Yes, It should be `kubectl taint node dashboard2.pvi.com  node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-`

Comment: Starting with `1.20` the command should be:
`kubectl taint node mymasternode  node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-`
See more: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#node-role-kubernetes-io-control-plane

Comment: "Suggested edit queue is full" when trying to edit answer. @Pascal is correct and should be added to this answer. Version <1.20 vs >1.20. Console output to add: `taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule" not found`

Answer (score 13):

Use the below command to untaint all masters

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Answer (score 11):

First, get the name of the master

```
kubectl get nodes

NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
yasin   Ready    master   11d   v1.13.4
```

as we can see there is one node with the name of `yasin` and the role is `master`. If we want to use it as worker we should run

```
kubectl taint nodes yasin node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Answer (score 10):

#### node-role.kubernetes.io/master

is deprecated in favor of:

#### node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane

Official kubernetes documentation: [node-role-kubernetes-io-master](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/labels-annotations-taints/#node-role-kubernetes-io-master)

So for versions +v1.20 the solution is :

```
kubectl taint node <master-node> node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule-
kubectl taint node <master-node> node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Comment: Upvoted but just to point out on my v1.24.0 installation I had both the `master` and `control-plane` taints and both had the `NoSchedule` effect and needed to be removed.

Comment: Thank you, yes I forgot to mention that both taints should be removed.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone using kops on AWS. I wanted to enable scheduling of Pods on master.

`$ kubectl get nodes -owide` was giving me this output:

```
NAME                                          STATUS
...
...
ip-1**-**-**-***.********.compute.internal    Ready                      node
ip-1**-**-**-***.********.master.internal     Ready,SchedulingDisabled   master
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ip-1**-**-**-***.********.compute.internal    Ready                      node
...
...
```

And `$ kubectl describe nodes ip-1**-**-**-***.********.master.internal`:

```
...
...
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      true
...                 ^^^^
...
```

**Patching the master** with this command:

`$ kubectl patch node MASTER_NAME -p "{\"spec\":{\"unschedulable\":false}}"`

worked for me and scheduling of Pods is now enabled.

Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/issues/639#issuecomment-287015882

Comment: This does work on the OP's bare-metal, e.g., "the-hard-way" installations as well. This patch also persists over kubelet upgrades, so extra points for that! Thanks.

Comment: Beautifully worked!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why the master node shows up as `NotReady`; it shouldn't. Try executing `kubectl describe node mymasternode` to find out.

The `SchedulingDisabled` is because the master node is *tainted* with `dedicated=master:NoSchedule`

Execute this command against all your masters to remove the taint:

```
kubectl taint nodes mymasternode dedicated-
```

To understand why that works read up on [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/).

Answer (score 2):

## Allow scheduling of pods on the master

```
kubectl taint node --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

### Verify the master isn't tainted

```
kubectl describe node | egrep -i taint
```

`Taints:             <none>`

### Schedule and run test pod in master

```
kubectl run -it  busybox-$RANDOM --image=busybox --restart=Never -- date
```

This answer is a combination of other SO answers, from Victor G, Aryak Sengupta, and others.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to list all taints in nodes and untaint the tainted one.

```
root@lab-a:~# kubectl get nodes -o json | jq ".items[]|{name:.metadata.name, taints:.spec.taints}"
{
  "name": "lab-a",
  "taints": null
}
{
  "name": "lab-b",
  "taints": [
    {
      "effect": "NoSchedule",
      "key": "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
    }
  ]
}
```

lab-a does not have any taint.
so we untaint lab-b:

```
root@lab-a:~# k taint node lab-b node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
node/lab-b untainted
```

Install jq in ubuntu by: `apt-get install jq`

Answer (score 0):

Since Openshift 4.x CoreOs is directly integrated on Kubernetes configuration (you can make all masters schedulable this way

```
# edit the field spec.mastersSchedulable to set a value true
$ oc patch schedulers.config.openshift.io cluster --type json \
     -p '[{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/mastersSchedulable", "value": true}]'
```

or using

```
oc edit schedulers.config.openshift.io cluster
```

and edit the field

```
spec:
    mastersSchedulable: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

according to: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#control-plane-node-isolation

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane-
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?