# How to use the master node as worker node in Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use the resources of master node of kubernetes cluster for my application which will be launched.

How to use the master node as worker node in Kubernetes cluster?

I have two nodes setup. I can launch a job from master node which is running on worker node. But I dont want to waste my Master node resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

> By default, your cluster will not schedule pods on the master for
>   security reasons. If you want to be able to schedule pods on the
>   master, e.g. for a single-machine Kubernetes cluster for development,
>   run:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Comment: Running this command gives me an error "error: at least one taint update is required"

Answer (score 4):

As [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147941/allow-scheduling-of-pods-on-kubernetes-master/55377425#55377425)

First, get the name of the master

```
kubectl get nodes

NAME     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
yasin   Ready    master   11d   v1.13.4
```

as we can see there is one node with the name of yasin and the role is master. If we want to use it as worker we should run

```
kubectl taint nodes yasin node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

Answer (score 3):

according to [this link](https://forum.linuxfoundation.org/discussion/861364/lab-20-1-2-not-working):

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane-
```

It seems the `master-` keyword is not working for the new kubernetes versions.