# How to run a pod(s) on a master node(s) in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm aware that running a pod(s) on a master node(s) is against kubernetes best practices! Nevertheless, in my virtual environment, I'd like to run a pod on a master node. How can I do that?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866725/609290

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution. You can remove `taint` that prohibits `kubernetes scheduler` to schedule pods on a master node(s).

```sh
# Get all nodes.
$ kubectl get nodes
NAME        STATUS   ROLES     AGE   VERSION
compute01   Ready    compute   16d   v1.15.0
master      Ready    master    16d   v1.15.0
web01       Ready    web       16d   v1.15.0

# Check if there is a NoSchedule taint on master node.  
$ kubectl get node master -o json
...
"taints": [
    {
        "effect": "NoSchedule",
        "key": "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
    }
]
...

# Delete node-role.kubernetes.io/master taint from all nodes that have it.
$ kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
node "node/master" untainted
taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" not found
taint "node-role.kubernetes.io/master" not found
```

If you want make you master node schedulable again then, you will have to recreate deleted taint with bellow command.

```sh
$ kubectl taint node master node-role.kubernetes.io/master=:NoSchedule
node/master tainted
```