# How to load balance pod distribution between master+worker and only worker node in a kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-deployment

I have one k8s cluster with two nodes. One node lets say A, is a master+worker and the other B, is a worker only. Now, whenever a new deployment happens it goes to the worker node (B). I tried with multiple deployments and each of them got deployed on worker node (B) only.

I think its the behavior of scheduler to schedule deployments on worker node and keep master as low utilized as possible.

I want to distribute deployments in a round-robin manner so that if I have 6 deployments, each node would receive 3. I understand that I can do it by defining node constraints in the deployment file, but I wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve this?

Note- I tried a deployment with two replicas and both nodes received one pod. But the same is not the case with single replica. It always deployed on worker node (B) only.

Node A (master + worker) taint config

```
CreationTimestamp:  Thu, 18 Apr 2019 11:38:54 +0200
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
```

Node B (worker only) taint config

```
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 10 Dec 2019 08:37:25 +0100
Taints:             <none>
Unschedulable:      false
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Allow scheduling of pods on Kubernetes master?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147941/allow-scheduling-of-pods-on-kubernetes-master)

Answer (score 0):

You can run below command remove taint on master and all nodes

```
kubectl taint node --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to distribute deployments in a round-robin manner so that if I have 6 deployments, each node would receive 3. I understand that I can do it by defining node constraints in the deployment file, but I wanted to know if there is any other way to achieve this?

First; you should not care about low-level details about scheduling. Let Kubernetes be responsible for that.

### PodAffinity or PodAntiAffinity

The two things that you should care about regarding pod scheduling is wether a pod should be **co-located** with something else, or if a pod should **avoid to be co-located** with something. E.g. you may have want your application replicas to be scheduled on different nodes for fault tolerance / high availability.

See [Pod Affinity and Pod Anti-Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity)

Answer (score 0):

The k8s component doing taking pods distribution decision is called "**Scheduler**", it takes its decision according to filtering and distribution policies

Filtering options

- *Node Taints* as we have on master by default, the pod must tolerate node taints to bypass the limitation

```
kubectl get node -l kubernetes.io/role=master -o json | jq '.items[].spec.taints'
```

```
  {
    "effect": "NoSchedule",
    "key": "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
  }
```

- *Resources requests*, so Pod CPU and memory requests should be less than available resources on nodes.
- *NodeAffinities/AntiAffinities*, Raise a condition of schedule depending on node labels
- *PodAffinities/AntiAffinities* , Same like NodeAff* but depending on other pod labels

**Notes**.

- All filters options has a soft and hard level of scheduling
  soft keywords "Preferred"
  hard keyworks "NoSchedule ,required "
- you can create your custom Scheduler that can apply your own thoughts and priorities.