# Can i install Kubernates cluster on single machine?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, centos, openshift, minikube

i have only one instance machine which is  centos-7 minimal installation. can i install kubernates cluster as a master and node same machine(without minikube and micro8s). is there any possible way?

Thanks.

Comment: You could set up two VMs and run Docker within those.

Comment: Since this question is related to Openshift have you tried: https://www.okd.io/minishift/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [kind](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/kind/). Kind is a tool for running local Kubernetes clusters using Docker container. So on the same machine docker containers are created for each Kubernetes node.

Also you can install a single node Kubernetes cluster using [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) and the master node can be [marked as schedule-able](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147941/allow-scheduling-of-pods-on-kubernetes-master) so that pods can be scheduled on the master node.