# configure haproxy ingress on k8s v19 for jenkins application on Redhat Linux 7.9 server

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, haproxy-ingress

I am deploying the Jenkins application using k8s v19 on Redhat 7.9 machine.I could able to connect to an application URL with port number(jenkins-test-ci.xyz.com:32419(node port).) but not able to log in via **jenkins-test-ci.xyz.com**.

I have configured Nodeport service and Ingress rule as below

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: jenkins-test-svc
  name: jenkins-test-svc
  namespace: ci-cd
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - name: webui
      port: 8080
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 8080
    - name: jnlp
      port: 50000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 50000
  selector:
    app: jenkins-test
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: jenkins-test
  namespace: ci-cd
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - jenkins-test-ci.xyz.com
    secretName: qa-pss-ci
  rules:
  - host: jenkins-test-ci.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: jenkins-test-svc
            port:
              number: 8080
```

> [root@xyz deployments]# kubectl logs haproxy-ingress-snkjc -n
> ingress-controller

```
I0105 09:13:06.968207       6 launch.go:142]
Name:       HAProxy
Release:    v0.7.1
Build:      git-5dc0d6f
Repository: https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress
I0105 09:13:06.968268       6 launch.go:145] Watching for ingress class: haproxy
I0105 09:13:06.969008       6 launch.go:345] Creating API client for https://x.x.x.x:443
I0105 09:13:06.977711       6 launch.go:357] Running in Kubernetes Cluster version v1.19 (v1.19.6) - git (clean) commit fbf646b339dc52336b55d8ec85c181981b86331a - platform linux/amd64
I0105 09:13:06.979849       6 launch.go:169] validated ingress-controller/ingress-default-backend as the default backend
I0105 09:13:06.984382       6 controller.go:1496] starting Ingress controller
I0105 09:13:06.992673       6 event.go:218] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"ci-cd", Name:"jenkins-test", UID:"b06bb11c-427c-4fe6-a543-8f6d1705237c", APIVersion:"extensions", ResourceVersion:"1230711", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' Ingress ci-cd/jenkins-test
I0105 09:13:12.322064       6 controller.go:1504] running initial sync of secrets
I0105 09:13:12.323590       6 backend_ssl.go:71] adding secret ci-cd/qa-pss-ci to the local store
I0105 09:13:12.323760       6 leaderelection.go:174] attempting to acquire leader lease...
W0105 09:13:12.325376       6 controller.go:521] service ingress-controller/ingress-default-backend does not have any active endpoints
I0105 09:13:12.325579       6 controller.go:332] backend reload required
I0105 09:13:12.330463       6 leaderelection.go:184] successfully acquired lease ingress-controller/ingress-controller-leader-haproxy
I0105 09:13:12.330511       6 status.go:199] new leader elected: haproxy-ingress-snkjc
I0105 09:13:12.358898       6 controller.go:341] ingress backend successfully reloaded...
I0105 09:13:16.360882       6 controller.go:332] backend reload required
I0105 09:13:16.394526       6 controller.go:341] ingress backend successfully reloaded...
```

Please suggest to fix this issue.Thank you

Comment: What error do you get when trying to log in by `Ingress` resource? How exactly did you deploy the `HAProxy`? Have you tried to expose other workload like `nginx` with your `HAProxy`? Does it work?

Comment: I deployed haproxy-ingress controller github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress" and error which i got as below [root@xyz deployments]# curl jenkins-test-ci.xyz.com curl: (7) Failed connect to jenkins-test-ci.xyz.com:80; Connection refused [root@xyz deployments]# kubectl get svc -n ci-cd NAME TYPE CLUSTER-IP EXTERNAL-IP PORT(S) AGE jenkins-test-svc NodePort 10.97.1.1 <none> 8080:32454/TCP,50000:30251/TCP 9m34s , but i could able to login using url:nodeport.  Please suggest to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

Without additional information regarding (like i the actual setup of your `HAProxy Ingress controller` it could be hard to pinpoint the actual issue.

There are conflicting information in your question related to the provisioning of your `HAProxy Ingress Controller`:

- Logs from your question are pointing to:

  - *[Github.com: Jcmoraisjr: Haproxy-ingress](https://github.com/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress)*
- A comment that you made is pointing to:

  - *[Github.com: Haproxytech: Kubernetes-ingress](https://github.com/haproxytech/kubernetes-ingress)*

---

The most probable cause that you are getting connection refused is that the `Service` of your `HAProxy Ingress Controller` is configured in a way that doesn't allow you to just hit the: `http://jenkins-test-ci.xyz.com` (port 80).

Assuming that you followed the documentation (either one), both solutions **use `Service` of type `NodePort` to allow the inbound traffic to hit the controller**. This is inherently forcing your `Ingress` resources to be available on **`node_ip:nodeport`** (`nodeport` port range: `30000`-`32767`):

You can check how your `Ingress` controller is exposed by running:

- `$ kubectl get svc -n NAMESPACE`

The output of above command should be similar to:

```sh
NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                     AGE
haproxy-ingress           NodePort    10.233.39.4     <none>        80:32149/TCP,443:30011/TCP,1024:31532/TCP   3h56m
ingress-default-backend   ClusterIP   10.233.18.215   <none>        8080/TCP                                    3h56m
```

Following this example if you have an app exposed with an `Ingress` resource and you would like to connect to it, you would need to connect to `node_ip:32149` (see the ports on the `haproxy-ingress`).

To be able to expose your `Jenkins` on ports like `80` and/or `443` with an `Ingress` resource you will need to use `Service` of type `LoadBalancer`. **The `Service` that is used to expose your `HAProxy Ingress Controller` will need to be changed from `NodePort` to `LoadBalancer` type.**

This `Service` (`LoadBalancer`) will require you to "provide" an IP address that could be allocated for this specific reason. With provider managed Kubernetes solution like `GKE`, `EKS` or `AKS` this process is automated. For solutions that are on premise you will need to use `MetalLB`:

> Kubernetes does not offer an implementation of network load-balancers ([Services of type LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)) for bare metal clusters. The implementations of Network LB that Kubernetes does ship with are all glue code that calls out to various IaaS platforms (GCP, AWS, Azure…). If you’re not running on a supported IaaS platform (GCP, AWS, Azure…), LoadBalancers will remain in the “pending” state indefinitely when created.
>
> Bare metal cluster operators are left with two lesser tools to bring user traffic into their clusters, “NodePort” and “externalIPs” services. Both of these options have significant downsides for production use, which makes bare metal clusters second class citizens in the Kubernetes ecosystem.
>
> MetalLB aims to redress this imbalance by offering a Network LB implementation that integrates with standard network equipment, so that external services on bare metal clusters also “just work” as much as possible.
>
> - *[Metallb.universe.tf](https://metallb.universe.tf/)* (you can find in this link the configuration and usage examples)

---

Additional resources:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Services networking: Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)*
- *[Banzaicloud.com: Blog: Load balancer services in on-prem environment](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/load-balancing-on-prem/)*

Comment: Thanks for the information .The above issue got fixed  after schedule pods on the Kubernetes control-plane master node(Haproxy ingress controller).
command executed:- kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147941/allow-scheduling-of-pods-on-kubernetes-master